# IIS 10 crash - global URL Rewrite rules

Tags: iis, iis-10

I have a Windows Server 2019 machine with IIS 10.

I want to create a global URL Rewrite Rule, but when I click on "Add rule", choose "Blank rule" and click on OK, the IIS window disappears. The IIS window crashes. How can this issue be solved?

I've tried "%windir%\System32\Inetsrv\InetMgr.exe /reset" and "iisreset". I've also removed every IIS entry under the Windows Roles and uninstalled "IIS-URL-Rewrite-Modul 2". After that I added the IIS roles and installed the "IIS-URL-Rewrite-Modul 2" again, without luck.

When I create a blank rule under a site, it works and the window does not crash.

Thank you!

Comment: IIS Manager is a .NET application itself. Attach a debugger and learn why it crashes.

Comment: Did you get any error messages when IIS window disappears?

Comment: I do not get error messages when the IIS window disappears.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. There was a problem with the file applicationHost.config in the directory C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Config

Comment: Has your problem been solved?

Comment: Yes, the problem has been solved.

Comment: I'm so glad that the problem has been resolved. It is so appreciated if you can share and mark your solution as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thank you very much. There was a problem with the file applicationHost.config in the directory C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Config